# Camera Movements in Roma

Tags: cinematography, roma

According to Alfonso Cuarón, the scene in which Cleo is turning off the lights contains 45 different camera positions. Why couldn't he do the scene simply with a 360-degree panning shot?

Has he commented on his reasoning for this?

Comment: I've tried to bring the question more on-topic for us. It might be that the director has commented on his reasoning.

Comment: Thank you. What I meant was, can't we get the exact same result with a single camera panning? and if not, why not?

Comment: Do you have a link to a clip?

Comment: No, I couldn't find the clip on youtube or elsewhere.